# Keeping maximum values on diagonals in matrix

Tags: r, matrix

Let's say I have a matrix A which represents elevation values:

```
A = matrix(c(100,105,106,109,101,101,106,104,107,106,101,102,105,106,108,102,102,104,110,104),
           nrow=5, ncol=4)
```

I would like to create a new matrix created out diagonal analysis of the A matrix. Starting in ex. the upper-left corner I want to analyse each diagonal and keeping the maximum values step by step. The expected results should be as following:

```
B = matrix(c(100,105,106,109,101,101,106,105,107,109,101,102,106,106,108,102,102,102,110,106),
           nrow=5, ncol=4)
```

Does anyone could help me with that?

Comment: Based on your description, I think one value in your `B` matrix is not correct: `B[3,4]`. Shouldn't that be `104`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, than you want the cummulative maximum for each diagonal. With `cummax` and two for-loops you can get what you want:

```
A[row(A)==col(A)] <- cummax(A[row(A)==col(A)])

for(i in 1:(nrow(A)-1)) {
  A[row(A)==col(A)-i] <- cummax(A[row(A)==col(A)-i])
}

for(i in 1:(ncol(A)-1)) {
  A[row(A)-i==col(A)] <- cummax(A[row(A)-i==col(A)])
}
```

Now matrix `A` looks like:

> ```
> > A
>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
> [1,]  100  101  101  102
> [2,]  105  106  102  102
> [3,]  106  105  106  104
> [4,]  109  107  106  110
> [5,]  101  109  108  106
> ```

---

You can also wrap this in a function if you need this procedure more often:

```
diagcummax <- function(m) {
  m[row(m)==col(m)] <- cummax(m[row(m)==col(m)])

  for(i in 1:(nrow(m)-1)) {
    m[row(m)==col(m)-i] <- cummax(m[row(m)==col(m)-i])
  }

  for(i in 1:(ncol(m)-1)) {
    m[row(m)-i==col(m)] <- cummax(m[row(m)-i==col(m)])
  }
  m
}
```

Then you just have to do:

```
diagcummax(A)
```

to get the desired result.

---

If you want to strat from the upper-right corner and then downward-left, you need to include `rev` at some points in the function:

```
diagcummax.upright <- function(m) {
  m[row(m)==rev(col(m))] <- rev(cummax(rev(m[row(m)==rev(col(m))])))

  for(i in 1:(nrow(m)-1)) {
    m[row(m)==rev(col(m))-i] <- rev(cummax(rev(m[row(m)==rev(col(m))-i])))
  }

  for(i in 1:(ncol(m)-1)) {
    m[row(m)-i==rev(col(m))] <- rev(cummax(rev(m[row(m)-i==rev(col(m))])))
  }
  m
}
```

Now with:

```
diagcummax.upright(A)
```

the following matrix is returned:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]  100  101  101  102
[2,]  105  106  102  102
[3,]  106  104  105  104
[4,]  109  107  106  110
[5,]  107  106  110  104
```

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what I was looking for! Just two short question: 1) How should I modify the code to start from the upper-right corner? 2) Would it be possible to make kind of diagonal analysis by applying the cumulation of the values at the certain angle ex 35 degrees (regarding one the chosen corners)?

Comment: @PaulG 35 degrees isn't possible as far as I know; for starting from the upper-right corner you have to wrap the `col(A)`-part in `rev` like this: `A[row(A)==rev(col(A))]`

Comment: Thank you, a lot. I did some research and haven't seen any possibility to do such thing with degrees. Anyway, thank you a lot for your kind help. It was exactly what I was looking for!